# How to add libraries to Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I'm a beginner trying to figure out libraries. I've read through many previous questions on how to do this, but the answers are not helping me. Here is my current situation:

```
import src.main.java.org.reflections.Reflections;

public class HelpMe {

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");
}
```

Here are my project run-time libraries:

[image]

And here is the reflections package:

[image]

**I am getting these errors:**

error: package src.main.java.org.reflections does not exist

error: cannot find symbol
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");
symbol:   class Reflections

Comment: Make sure your runtime librarie  e.g reflections  is compiled.

Comment: Is there a straightforward way of doing this? My Reflections library is already also in the Compile-time Libraries in my project properties. Is there another step required to compile a library?

Comment: Right click your main project lib then add project(Reflections). Select lib project jar file. Thats it.

Comment: In the Projects window, under my project and inside of the Libraries container is already the Reflections library. It was added there automatically when I added Reflections to my project properties - libraries list. Also, when i tried to follow your steps exactly and right clicked Libraries - add project - Reflections even though it was already in the list, I got the error: "This project cannot be added because it does not produce a JAR file using an Ant script."

Comment: Ok , you are using ant script but not mentioned in question. I just added ant tag in question . So that other can understand whats going on. However you have to specify your Reflection jar file in ant script e.g Reflections/dist/jar

Comment: I have not yet looked into what Ant is, but I tried downloading a different file. This time it was a jar file and not just a normal folder.  It works now! Do libraries always have to be jars?

Comment: Exactly always looked for jar file. You can make your Refelections project into jar file , clean and build project then find dist folder where jar file located. Then add that jar file to main project as i said earlier. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the library in your project properties.

- Right Click on you project and choose "Properties"
- Navigate to Libraries and add it.

[image]

Comment: where can I find this in NetBeans 12.0?